# Form_for data not accessible in custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `form_for @user` to update a column in user model .
I have given html method as get and submitting to action look like

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]) 

@user_update_attribute(:phno,params[:phno])
```

and in view its look like

```
<%= form_for :@user, url: addphno_addphno_path , html: { method: :get }  %>
```

The issue is I am not able to get  data in controller action.the error is

> could not find record of "id="

Comment: in view its simple form_for @user and action path and html method get

Comment: Are you sure is that the correct code you posted? If so your code has two mistakes.

Comment: let me know the errors ,but this is just to give idea what problem i am facing.

Comment: please guide me to solve the issue ,i am new in rails

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have a separate "phoneno" action:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   match :addphone, via: [:get, :post]
end 

#app/views/users/add_phone_no.html.erb
<%= form_for @user, user_addphone_path(@user) do |f|  %>
   <%= f.text_field :number %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def addphone
     @user = User.find params[:id]
     @user.update( update_params ) if request.post?
  end

  private

  def update_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:phno)
  end
end
```

---

If you wanted to use the `update` action (as is convention):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end

   def update 
      @user = User.find params[:id]
      @user.update user_params
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:phno)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :phno %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

Bottom line is that you *should* be using the second batch of code if you're updating your `@user` object.

I originally thought you wanted to add a phone number as associative data to your `@user`... but it seems that you just wish to add a phone number for the user. To do this, the above code will suffice.

Comment: my main aim is redirect user to add phone number after omniauth login so i added a action path in after_sign_in_path method in application controller and save the added phone number to database.

Comment: You should put that stuff in your question, nothing worse than seeing a question which asks for code improvements but is actually part of a much bigger implementation

Comment: I have used devise gem for login and signup and omniauth-facebook

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding sir ..i am very new to rails so do n't know the scope of problem

Comment: np bud, just a way to get better answers next time :)

Comment: it will be very helpful for me ,,if you can guide me to implement this.

Comment: i have tried the second method you provided , in update method of UsersController ,but nothing in getting saved in database as phno paramater is not submitting to update action .

Comment: Started PATCH "/users/34/addphno" for ::1 
Processing by AddphnoController#addphno as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z/oB01ipXhhQvxUtkyJmIDZ4jxANJbRmiVcPacPfTntskL4YL8Yrx1uzjpw2l3mNEBUxapOMb/lefs0i89ooww==", "user"=>{"phno"=>"8888"}, "commit"=>"Update", "user_id"=>"34"}
  [SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 34 LIMIT 1
    UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`phno` = NULL WHERE `users`.`id` = 34
  Rendered addphno/addphno.html.erb (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 107ms (Views: 50.0ms | ActiveRecord: 48.0ms)

Comment: phno field is submitting in parameters section when in mysql update it is going null ..any idea